# How to get element index inside array

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I need to create attribute with the index value that the element has inside the array.

Using aggregate I can sort the array but I don't access the element.index attribute.

Using $map I can traverse the array but without success in accessing element.index.

Comment: We need more details to see how we can help, like sample documents and expected output and your current attempt. But first of all, have you checked out [includeArrayIndex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#std-label-unwind-includeArrayIndex)?

Comment: Looks like there's an open request for this [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-71428). The ticket description includes an approach to achieve this today using `$map`, `$range`, and `$arrayElemAt`